# How do I find names that appear once or more times in different colums

Tags: excel, filtering, conditional-formatting

My question is: I have a set of customers that have a certain number of products and I want to know which customer has 1, 2, 3, 4 or all the products. Each customer can have one or more of the 5 products and if so, their names come back in that product's specific column. My question is; how do I filter and show a name that appears in column A and any combination of the other columns Considering that each customer has to have product A to be in the list. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a sample of your data, including expected result.

Comment: Depending on your data setup, an Advanced Filter might be the solution

Answer (score 0):

To start with, i'm also not an expert in excel but as I understand your problem statement, with a simple formula I was able to derive if person with name in column A who owns product A does he owns Product B or not and similarly C, D, E.
[image: Sample View]

Now the formula that I used in the sheet is
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$7, $A2)

[image: Formula]

After you have done this you can simply hide the actual data cells.

[image: Better View]

Here 1 means Yes and 0 means No.

Hope this is sufficient view for you to work ahead. I'm sure there is a macro way of doing this thing more effeciently.